# Generating unit tests for my service implementations on the spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

after hours of tries and fails I come to you in hope of a solution.
I'm struggle making unit tests for my spring boot application. I'm using mockito and Junit 5.

My architecture is made out like this:

- A controller
- An interface of the service
- A implementation of the service interface
- A repository extending CrudRepository<Entity, Long>

For now I just want to test out my service implementation.

This is how it looks like for now :

`

```
@SpringBootTest public class ServiceImplTest{
        @Mock    
     private Entity e;


     @MockBean
     private EntityRepository entityRepository;
        
     @MockBean
     private EntityService entityService;
    
     @BeforeEach
         init(){
               e = new Entity();
               e.name ="abc";
          }
    
    
    
    @Test
     private simpleTest(){
        // saving my element in the mocked repository
        entityRepository.save(e);
    
    
        // I have a repository query to delete an element in a specific way. I ask it to return 1 if it receives the order to activate this method
        doReturn(1).when(entityRepository).specialDeleteEntity(1L);
    
    
       // in the code serviceDeleteEntity() does some operations then calls entityRepository.specialDeleteEntity
        int howMany = entityService.serviceDeleteEntity(1L);
    
    
         // this fails because there was nothing in the repository to be deleted 
         assertEquals(howMany, 1);
    
     }
}
```

I just have a feeling the the Mocked Repository is not connected to my Mocked Service and by this, the operations between them don't work.

I have also tried another solution where I didn't mock the repository , just in case :

```
@SpringBootTest class ServiceImplTest {
    @MockBean
    private EntityRepository mockEntityRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private EntityService entityService;
    
    
    @Test
    void testDelete() {
        // Given
        final Entity entity = new Entity();
        entity.name = "abc";
    
        // Setup
        when(mockEntityRepository.specialDeleteEntity(1L)).thenReturn(1);
    
        // When
        final int result = entityService.specialDeleteEntity(1L);
    
        // Then
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo(1);
        verify(mockEntityRepository).specialDeleteEntity(1L);
    }
}
```

I may lack some anotations or some methods maybe. I just want your advice on the problem and maybe a step towards the solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Though I only got a little idea about what you are seeking. I would suggest you to look SpyBean annotation as well instead of MockBean.

Comment: I think you should use the annotation `@Mock` on the repository and `@InjectMocks` on your service declaration to inject the repository or any other mock you have declared into the service.

Comment: Thank you all for your help but the issue is still on, sadly.
With Spybean, it modifies my real database :(
With Mock and InjectMocks , the 'result' variable is at 0. I think there is still no communication between the mocked repository and the mockedService ..

Comment: @FrenchCornichon The second example should work. What errors do you get?

Comment: The result is 0..; The repository and service don't seem to be aware of each other :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your test:

#### 1. Wrong use of mocks

A mock is a dummy implementation of a class. You use them to bypass the normal behaviour of those classes. For example, if you write a unit test for `EntityService`, you don't want to set up an entire database and insert/delete mock data. So in that case you want to mock dependencies such as `EntityRepository`.

This means that in your `EntityServiceTest` you should only be mocking `EntityRepository`. You shouldn't mock `Entity` because this class normally doesn't contain a lot of behaviour and you shouldn't mock `EntityService` because you want to test the actual behaviour of this service and not of a mock.

#### 2. Choose one mocking framework

Your test is currently using a combination of `@Mock` and `@MockBean`.
Both of these annotations allow you to mock a class.
The difference is that `@Mock` relies only on Mockito and `@MockBean` mocks the class and creates a Spring bean of it to use for autowiring.

This means that the `@MockBean` annotation only works when you run (a part of) your Spring Boot application.
This is why you use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation.
The downside is that this might require additional configuration and slows down the tests due to starting/stopping the application.

If you only need to unit test a single class with some mocks, it would be easier to write a test with Mockito only.
To do so, use the `@Mock` annotation and replace `@SpringBootTest` with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`:

```java
// Replace @SpringBootTest with @ExtendWith to enable testing with Mockito
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class EntityServiceTest {
    // Add @InjectMocks to the class where the mocks should be injected into.
    // Normally this is the class that you want to test
    @InjectMocks
    private EntityService service;
    // Use @Mock in stead of @MockBean
    @Mock
    private EntityRepository repository;

    // ...
}
```

#### 3. Test the behaviour of your class

As I mentioned before, a mock is a dummy implementation of a class.
So that means that if you call `repository.save(..)`, it doesn't really do anything as there's no behaviour and no database behind it.

What you actually want to test is whether the `service. serviceDeleteEntity()` method calls the `repository. specialDeleteEntity()` method with the right arguments.

This means that your second example of your test is the right way.
The only thing you don't need is the `entity` because your test doesn't rely on it (assuming that your service passes the id argument to the repository and returns the result of the query):

```java
@Test
void testDelete() {
    // Given
    when(mockEntityRepository.specialDeleteEntity(1L)).thenReturn(1);
    
    // When
    final int result = entityService.specialDeleteEntity(1L);
    
    // Then
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(1);
    verify(mockEntityRepository).specialDeleteEntity(1L);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explenations. The problem is that, even by doing what you said, the result is at 0 . I don't really understand why the service and the repository don't seem to be aware of each other :/

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @g00glen00b for the solution.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class EntityServiceImplTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private EntityServiceImpl entityServiceImpl;
    @Mock
    private EntityRepository entityRepository;

 
@Test{
   Entity e = new Entity();

   when(entityRepository.getEntityById(1L)).thenReturn(e);

   final Entity result = entityServiceImpl.getEntityById(1L);

   assertEquals(e, result);  
  }

}
```

The issue here was that i had to use MockitoExtension on one hand.

Another problem was that, in my service implementation method , there was a hidden "new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())" used to call the method in the repository.

So there was always a difference between the time I "promised" and the time created during the call of the service implementation.
Thank you again

Comment: In both `when()` and `verify()` you can work with `ArgumentMatchers.any()`. For example: `verify(mockEntityRepository).specialDeleteEntity(eq(1L), any());`. You can go even further and use the `ArgumentCaptor` API to extract the timestamp that wass passed to the repository so you can write some assertions.

Comment: You may also want to check the Java time API. These classes have methods to retrieve the current time, but also have a `Clock` class that allow you to freeze the current time (for example during tests).

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to insert the mocked repository into your service in order it to be used:
entityService.setRepository(mockEntityRepository);

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for your answer. The repository inside my service for now is like this :
` @Autowired
 private EntityRepository entityRepository;
`
I have to make like a set method in order to change the repository from afar ? Is it possible to do it when it's autowired ?
Thanks

Comment: Nowadays IDEs recommend not to use Autowired but injections. Create a constructor for service where you inject the repo.

Comment: Assuming that `EntityService` works corectly and that `EntityRepository` is injected either through constructor or field injection, then it isn't necessary to insert the mocked repository because spring will do that for you.